# overrule element with nth-child

Tags: css

```
.list_td:nth-child(even) {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
}

.overlay {
    background:rgba(240,0,92,0.4);
    color:#530724;
}

<td class="list_td overlay"></td>
```

How to overule `overlay` over `list_td:nth-child` without using `!important`

Comment: Doesn't `.list_td.overlay` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the rule more specific:

```
.list_td.overlay {
    background: rgba(240, 0, 92, 0.4);
    color: #530724;
}
```

In this case combination of two classes would have the same specificity as class + pseudo-class (`.list_td:nth-child`), but being put after it, will make `.list_td.overlay` more important.

Read about ["CSS Specificity"](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) and selector weights.

Comment: [W3C Link](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) just for reference :) *Edit:* Just saw that you had already included a link to Smashing Magazine article but leaving this comment as-is still.

Comment: Isn't nth-child a pseudo-class and not a pseudo-element ?

Comment: @vals You are actually right. Corrected. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.list_td.overlay {
    background:rgba(240,0,92,0.4);
    color:#530724;
}
```

working demo http://jsfiddle.net/qw10hwc6/1/